# making a PDF from a database table in vb.net

Tags: pdf, itext, vb.net-2010

i want to make a pdf report from data from a table in my database how do I do that in VB.net, everything I seen is how to do it with asp. or is it even possible. This is for a windows form.

ok after a while of research and playing around with my code I thought I would post it since it seems most of the itextsharp stuff is for c# or ASP.net This works for me and I was using VS express 2010. where it says dtg.reports that is where you are going to replace it with the name of your dataGridView. I hope this helps someone it was a pain and neck to get it to work.

Comment: Hi Chris, I see that your question received one down-votes and two votes to close the question. I think this happened *before* you updated your question. I think it would be better if you removed the solution from the question and used that code to create an answer. You can then accept your own answer and the question doesn't need to be closed.

Answer (score 1):

I have research a lot and with what I found and playing around with my code I found something that works so I hope this helps someone out. this solution is done in VB.net using VS express 2012 and has been working for me. ##### a note you are going to insert the name of your datagridview where it says dtgReport

```
Imports iTextSharp
Imports iTextSharp.text
Imports iTextSharp.text.pdf

'Creating iTextSharp Table from the DataTable data
Dim pdfTable As New PdfPTable(dtgReport.ColumnCount)
pdfTable.DefaultCell.Padding = 3
pdfTable.WidthPercentage = 30
pdfTable.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT
pdfTable.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 1

'Adding Header row
For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In dtgReport.Columns
    Dim cell As New PdfPCell(New Phrase(column.HeaderText))
    cell.BackgroundColor = New iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(240, 240, 240)
    pdfTable.AddCell(cell)
 Next

 'Adding DataRow
 For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dtgReport.Rows
     For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In row.Cells
         pdfTable.AddCell(cell.Value.ToString())
     Next
 Next

'Saving to PDF
Dim folderPath As String = "C:\reports\"
If Not Directory.Exists(folderPath) Then
    Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath)
End If

Using stream As New FileStream(folderPath & "test2.pdf", FileMode.Create)
    Dim pdfDoc As New Document(PageSize.A2, 10.0F, 10.0F, 10.0F, 0.0F)
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, stream)
    pdfDoc.Open()
    pdfDoc.Add(pdfTable)
    pdfDoc.Close()
    stream.Close()
End Using
```

Comment: where do i get itextsharp? it's not being recognized in my 2010 vb express